# C++ cannot use template template class with class member

Tags: c++, templates

I am possibly misunderstanding the template template classes and their use in C++. With the following declaration:

```
template <typename Parameter>
class A { Parameter p; };

template <template <typename> typename Class, typename Parameter>
class B { Class<Parameter> q; };

B<A, int> b;
b.q.p = 0;
```

I can declare a variable `b`, but I cannot access class members `p` nor `q`. That line yields these two errors:

```
error: unknown type name 'b'
b.q.p = 0;
^
error: cannot use dot operator on a type
b.q.p = 0;
 ^
```

Why is `b` not a variable, is it still a template? What is happening?

Comment: What compiler and compilation flags are you using?

Comment: I am using C++17 standard compiler without special flags: https://cppinsights.io/s/8622d352

Comment: It would be clearer to post the exact code you compiled in the question as a single block of code. The way you wrote the question, with text interleaved with code, some people have assumed you have a larger program and these bits were excerpts from the larger program.

Comment: @M.M You are completely right, I just edited the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written is correct and valid -- up until the assignment.

The reason that `b.q.p = 0;` fails is because `class` definitions default to `private` accessibility for all member definitions, so:

```cpp
template <typename Parameter>
class A { Parameter p; };

template <template <typename> typename Class, typename Parameter>
class B { Class<Parameter> q; };
```

defines both `p` and `q` as private members, not public; this causes `b.q` to fail when trying to access `q` (the same would occur with `q.p`).

Either make these members `public`, or make `class` a `struct` (which defaults to `public`) and this will work:

```cpp
template <typename Parameter>
struct A { Parameter p; };

template <template <typename> typename Class, typename Parameter>
struct B { Class<Parameter> q; };
```

<kbd>[**Live Example**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4r8W6vbWz)</kbd>

Comment: Lookup is not affected by access control.    Lookup can find a private member, and there may follow an error message would be that there is no access to that member

Comment: @M.M Poor wording on my part -- fixed. I wasn't referring to lookup in terms of name lookup rules; just in terms of accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

That code is almost legal, but classes have a default access specifier of `private`, so you need to mark them as `public`. This code works:

```
template <typename Parameter>
class A
{
public:
    Parameter p;
};

template <template <typename> typename Class, typename Parameter>
class B
{
public:
    Class<Parameter> q;
};

int main()
{
    B<A, int> b;
    b.q.p = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because statements are not allowed outside of functions, unless that statement is a declaration. The error messages arise from the compiler trying to parse the code as a declaration. This is nothing to do with templates; you would see the same error with the simpler code:

```
struct { int x; } y;

y.x = 0;
```

The attempted assignment can occur inside a function, e.g.:

```
int main()
{
    b.q.p = 0;
}
```

which will now give an error message about access control, that you can fix by making the members public.